# Take max from SubQuery

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need little help with TSql :)

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT HSW, NAZWA, COUNT(HSW) AS TEST 
FROM _Katalogi.dbo.ZBIOR_NAZW 
WHERE hsw = '3768917680' 
GROUP BY HSW, NAZWA
```

Now I get this results

```
3768917680  PODKŁADKA UTWARDŹ.          1
3768917680  ŚRUBA SAMOZABEZPIECZJĄCA    1
3768917680  PODKŁADKA                  82
3768917680  PODKŁADKA 3/8"              1
3768917680  PODKŁADKA UTWARDZONA     2883
3768917680  ŚRUBA                       2
```

Now in this subquery I need to take only

```
3768917680  PODKŁADKA UTWARDZONA         2883
```

### With max COUNT(HSW) AS TEST

I thin i ask a little bit wrong

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT HSW, NAZWA, COUNT(HSW) AS TEST 
FROM _Katalogi.dbo.ZBIOR_NAZW 
GROUP BY HSW, NAZWA
```

Goal is take only top NAZWA from table gropuing by HSW column . Like u see a little bit up i have one HSW number and many names and i need to get only most popular name :) but inside one HSW group. there is many hsw numbers which have many differend names and i need only list of HSW numbers with TOP name :) Any ideas ?

differend aproach :)
Data in table

```
3768917680  PODKŁADKA UTWARDŹ.          
3768917680  ŚRUBA SAMOZABEZPIECZJĄCA    
3768917680  PODKŁADKA                  
3768917680  PODKŁADKA                  
3768917680  PODKŁADKA                  
3768917680  PODKŁADKA 3/8"              
3768917680  PODKŁADKA UTWARDZONA     
3768917680  ŚRUBA                       
3768917681  PODKŁADKA UTWARDŹ.          
3768917681  PODKŁADKA UTWARDŹ.  
3768917681  ŚRUBA SAMOZABEZPIECZJĄCA    
3768917682  PODKŁADKA                  
3768917683  PODKŁADKA 3/8"              
3768917684  PODKŁADKA UTWARDZONA     
3768917684  ŚRUBA                       
3768917684  ŚRUBA
```

like u see this is on emess so i need get only what is goo so most popular name in group

```
3768917680  PODKŁADKA

3768917681  PODKŁADKA UTWARDŹ. 

3768917682  PODKŁADKA                  

3768917683  PODKŁADKA 3/8"

3768917684  ŚRUBA
```

so goal take one hsw number with top (most popular) name

Comment: What if two records have the same highest count?

Comment: You want the row that has the highest count of PODKŁADKA UTWARDZONA, or the row with the highest count?

Comment: yes like all "top names" when i group by HSW number.

Comment: So for each HSW, you want the top performing NAZWA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HSW ORDER BY CNT DESC) rn
        ,       *
        FROM    (
                SELECT  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY HSW, NAZWA) as CNT
                ,       *
                FROM    FROM _Katalogi.dbo.ZBIOR_NAZW 
                ) as SubQuery1
        ) as SubQuery2
WHERE   rn = 1 -- Only top CNT per HSW
```

Comment: Thx for ansfer but i ask wrong quetion i think. pls see edited question :)

Comment: Query updated to select one row per `hsw` that has the highest count

Comment: its working TX but i still dont undestand how :) i need make more time to swallow this :)

Comment: @Goat_CO: If you use `count() over (...)`, the extra subquery is required

Comment: Just thought my method was more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
SELECT HSW, NAZWA, COUNT(HSW) AS TEST 
FROM _Katalogi.dbo.ZBIOR_NAZW 
WHERE hsw = '3768917680' 
GROUP BY HSW, NAZWA
HAVING  COUNT(HSW) = 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(HSW) AS TEST 
    FROM _Katalogi.dbo.ZBIOR_NAZW 
    WHERE hsw = '3768917680' 
    GROUP BY HSW, NAZWA
    ORDER BY COUNT(HSW) DESC
)
```

Comment: hmm sth like tha but i thin i ask a little bit wron .. I will eduit post :)

Comment: Missing an `order by` in the subquery

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an analytic function to create a RowRank based on COUNT, this will take all results if there is a tie, and perform well.

If you wanted the top result for all HSW's and not just the one listed you could use:

```
SELECT HSW, NAZWA, TEST
FROM (
     SELECT  HSW, NAZWA, COUNT(HSW) AS TEST, Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY HSW ORDER BY COUNT(HSW) DESC) as RowRank
     FROM _Katalogi.dbo.ZBIOR_NAZW 
     GROUP BY HSW, NAZWA
     )sub
WHERE RowRank = 1
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5bff3/2/0)

If you don't want multiple results in case of a tie, change RANK() to ROW_NUMBER(), then it will choose just 1 for each HSW.

Edit: Missing ')'

Comment: I think he wants this solution, but without where hsw='...'?

Comment: sec i thik we mees the poin i will preparte beter View of data

Comment: This will get you what you want, it creates a rank for each grouping of HSW, NAZQA based on Count from highest to lowest, returning the top 1 for each HSW.

Comment: @AndrzejSiwek, please prepare both the source data and what you want the result to be.